# MacBook Pro 2013 NVME booting Issues

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, startup, ssd

A while back I did an SSD upgrade on my 15" MacBook Pro 2013.  The SSD I'm using is an ADATA SX6000 256gb.  I purchased the Sintech adapter to use with this drive and I had no issues installing MacOS Mojave or any of the sleep issues that I've seen people have online.

However, after a month of use my MacBook suddenly won't boot and all I can see is a folder with a question mark flashing.  I thought maybe the new SSD unfortunately failed but when I installed it into my main PC it was able to recognize it without any issues.

What I'm wondering is if this is an adpater problem as the original drive still works with this MacBook, it's only the new one that doesn't.

I'm looking for help or advice on how I can narrow down the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have pretty much answered your own question.

1. Tried SSD on another system and it works, CHECK
2. Old drive works fine, so it's not the Mac, CHECK

This points directly to the only other piece of hardware you haven't tested elsewhere, the adapter. So, unless you can test that adapter and drive in another similar Mac I would say you should replace the adapter.

Note that I have been doing computer support (Macs, PCs) for a long time and have learned that *nothing* is always as simple as that. Your issue seems cut and dried, and if I was a betting man I would bet on the adapter being the culprit. But computers are complex beasts and don't always yield to logic. They're too complicated, too many parts interacting in too many ways, for everything to be bug free.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I ordered another (different) adapter and i'm going to see if that is the problem.  I just wasn't sure if that was 100% the case and if there was any of troubleshooting I could do. I'm just curious as to how the adapter could fail so easily as it isn't a complex piece of hardware, just rewires the new ssd into the slot of my Macbook's. Who knows maybe I just got a bad one.

Comment: Indeed, and I share your reservations, and wish you well in avoiding Murphy's Law ;-)

Comment: Nice answer! Simple, clear, and just the right measure of caution! :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone that commented! I ended up getting a new (different brand) adapter and my Macbook recognized my nvme with no problem. I've had no issues so far.